# How to change color of column graph dynamically using Extjs?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

I have done application using Extjs. Requirement is need to change color of column graph dynamically after February. Find the attached image, **here i have two fields based on that i plot column graph**. I am showing two different fields with different color as column in graph. **My problem is after February month, i need to change the color of one column to different color (marked in attached image)**. but field value will be the same only need to change color. If i plot the graph by hard coded value, easily i can change color for particular month. but here i am plotting the graph based on store value dynamically. **Can any tell me how to achieve this one in Extjs? is it possible or not in extjs?**. Great appropriated. Thank you

[image: Column graph]

**Here is my code:**

```
Ext.define('Ext.chart.theme.ColumnColorTheme', {
    extend: 'Ext.chart.theme.Base',
    constructor: function(config) {
        this.callParent([Ext.apply(
        {        

            axisTitleLeft: {
                font:'15px Arial',
                fill:'#0185d7'
            },
            axisTitleRight: {
                font:'15px Arial',
                fill:'#0185d7'
            },
            colors: ['rgb(50, 150, 255)','rgb(0, 70, 100)']
        }, config)]);
    }
});

Ext.define('Myweb.view.UtilizationReportGraphView',
{
    extend:'Ext.chart.Chart',
    requires:['Ext.chart.series.Column','Ext.chart.series.Line','Ext.chart.axis.Numeric','Ext.chart.axis.Category'],
    alias:'widget.utilizationView',
    id:'utilizationViewId',
    theme:'ColumnColorTheme',    
    height:window.innerHeight/2,
    width:window.innerWidth,
    store:'RevenueReportStore',
    legend:{
        position:'top'      
    },
    axes:[
    {
        type: 'Numeric',
        position: 'left',
        fields: ['dayRateBudget','dayRateActual'],
        minimum:0 
    },
    {
        type: 'Category',
        position: 'bottom',
        fields: ['month'] 
    },
    {
        title: 'Variance in %',
        type: 'Numeric',
        position: 'right',
        fields: ['utilizationPercentage']
    }
    ],
    series: [
    {
        type: 'column',
        axis: 'left',
        xField: 'month',
        yField: ['dayRateBudget','dayRateActual'],
        groupGutter:20,
        gutter:100,
        title:['Budget','Actual']
    },   
        {
        type: 'line',
        axis: 'right',
        xField: 'month',
        yField: ['utilizationPercentage'],
        markerConfig: {
            type: 'circle',
            fill:'red',
            stroke:'red',
            'stroke-width': 0
        },
        style:{
            stroke:'red',
            'stroke-width': 2
        },
        title:['Variance']

    }
    ]       
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a `renderer` function on your column `series` like this:

```
renderer: function (sprite, record, attr, index) {
    var color = '#000000'; //some logic here

    return Ext.apply(attr, {
        fill: color
    });
}
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/PSPM6/

Comment: Look at this example: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/example/charts/BarRenderer.html

Comment: I have tried above link.they have only one column and changing, but i have two columns within that i need change one column color. also while looping some time record is undefind.

Comment: I've added a link to a working example. according to a comment in documentation you can get the record using `chart.series.items[known series index].items[index].storeItem`.